# how do I get a list of syscall numbers from my ubuntu distribution?

Tags: glibc

This question may be a little clean and green. I'm looking to retrieve a list of syscall numbers like in [this post](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/).

Comment: You didn't provide details as to your Ubuntu distribution, but the system calls to the kernel aren't unique to Ubuntu; standard linux kernel calls can be used (according to the version of kernel you are using). If you are using GNOME, use the gtk+/glib calls appropriate for the version of gnome being used; if using Unity ... (Unity alone is Ubuntu specific, but its mostly gtk+/glib anyway) ... Ubuntu for the most part is standard upstream (the more changes made, the more it costs to maintain...)   if you like that site; use it (checking only that versions [of api's] match!)

Comment: hihi thanks for replying, I'm a total newbie who is reading up. I figured I'll just go into arch/x86/unistd.h and do a grep.